# Angular 7 HTTP put strips out undefined property

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to send a HTTP PUT request to an API that accepts a JSON object in its body. Everything works fine, except if I want to set a prop of the body to `undefined`, that prop will be stripped out entirely from the response object (as if I would call the `delete` operator for that prop). I checked and I can confirm that the given prop is there, with the value of `undefined` as long as the object is passed to `httpClient.put()`.

Does anybody know why does this happen? Is this an expected behavior for the http client, or there's a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you describe it's the expected behavior of `HttpClient`. Actually, it's the behavior of `JSON.stringify()` which `HttpClient` uses behind the scenes.

Unlike JavaScript, JSON doesn't have the concept of `undefined`. If something is undefined, it's just not defined. It doesn't exist at all.
So, when `JSON.stringify()` gets an object with a property that equals `undefined`, it omits him.

If you need this property in your request's body, try to change its value to `null`, empty string, or zero (depending on your server-side).

Comment: Yup, that's definitely what I did after (set it to `null`). I came to the same conclusion that you wrote after studying JSON specs.